# CNN architecture keras

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have to design a CNN architecture for Face Expression Recognition. I find a lot of examples about this on Internet which differ on CNN architecture. I'm trying to find out about the features which determinate the difference between the different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

There are some architectures who use pure CNN (without RNN or etc.) and do a pretty good job actually! One of them is shown in the image below:

[image: Facial Expression with CNN]

Although, this architecture (shown in the image) is pretty simple. There are some state-of-the-art architectures that their goal is "RealTime Facial Expression classification" with CNNs.Below, I put some links to related papers on this topic and how to train an efficient model for doing this task:

1- [Real Time Emotion Recognition from Facial Expressions Using CNN Architecture - IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8895215)

2- [Real-Time Facial Expression Recognition Based on CNN - Researcher Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335642398_Real-Time_Facial_Expression_Recognition_Based_on_CNN)

3- [Facial Expressions using CNNs - Researcher Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Facial-expressions-recognition-general-CNN-architecture-With-preprocessing-the-input_fig4_331681396)

4- [Emotion-Net 2 - Github](https://github.com/co60ca/EmotionNet2)

and every day, there are new models and architectures for this task that outperform eachOther!